# Cannot get MySQL database to change character set

Tags: mysql

I was getting an "Illegal mix of collations" error on my database, so I figured I should go ahead and set my database and all tables to UTF-8.

I found the command on how to do that () but I got the following error:

```
1 - Can't create/write to file './databasename/db.opt' (Errcode: 2)
```

I then found this to help: [MySQL Error 1 (HY000) Trouble creating file Errcode 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/981029/mysql-error-1-hy000-trouble-creating-file-errcode-2) but the solution didn't work. I still get the same error.

I don't know what to do other than to drop the database and restore it, but that seems like a bit of an extreme solution. I'm also struggling to figure out how I can alter all the tables in the database, again short of a dump and restore.

Does anyone have suggestions on how I can fix this bug? Is dropping the database my only option? Is there some permission I'm unaware of?

Comment: What is your question though?

Comment: Sorry, that's what I get for posting a question when I'm tired. Updated for clarity.

Comment: Can you publish full error message and your sql query which getting this error please?

Answer (score 0):

This question is quite old, but putting this answer here for future reference.

The way I was able to resolve it was by logging into the mysql instance with **root user credentials**.

The reason the above error occurs (1 - Can't create/write to file './databasename/db.opt' (Errcode: 2) is a result of a permissions issue.  The currently logged in mysql user **doesn't have write permissions** for modifying that directory.

Using the 'root' user account resolved this error message.