# How to bring back PHPMyAdmin Functions View in the DB left-pane

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mariadb

Recently, the left-pane DB preview in PHPMyAdmin lost the Functions folder. Already struggling the entire day to search a solution, but I cannot find anything similar to this problem. Together with this problem, I notice that when I hit the Structure view of a table it doesnt load anymore the table structure, but via MySQL command line though I can see everything.

Following various other topics on other phpMyAdmin left-pane view problems, I have verified that my user has ALL privileges.

Restarting MySQL (MariaDB actually) causes no change in the above results

I expect as so far the left-pane to show me the Functions folder as well as showing me the tables structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just found the solution after 1 day of searches:   this one worked perfectly   [MySQL Error 1 (HY000) Trouble creating file Errcode 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/981029/mysql-error-1-hy000-trouble-creating-file-errcode-2)